# Corrupted row and columns when mouse is dragged

Tags: java, swing, jtable, mouselistener, jtabbedpane

I'm getting my head around `JTable` at the moment however this is now twice I have had this type of problem and I think its my method that's wrong,

I have a `JTabbedPane` with three tabs set up as tables, I ran tests to see if my detection of the selected tab worked and that I was grabbing row information and column information successfully.

I have added a `MouseListener` to the three tables and this reliably produces good results by grabbing the `getRow()` and `getColumn()` from the event! However this is not producing reliable results as I have found out now that if I click on a row, hold the mouse button and drag to another row before releasing the `getRow` and `getColumn` will give the cell clicked but the highlighted row will be the one I released on!

```
public void detectMouseClickRow(JTable aTabbedPane) {
        aCol = aTabbedPane.getSelectedColumn(); 
        aRow = aTabbedPane.getSelectedRow();
        valueAt = (String)aTabbedPane.getValueAt(aRow, aCol);
}
```

How can I get the Row and Column information for the highlighted row? Otherwise when someone comes to click a job to delete, they could select the wrong one?

Comment: `getSelectedRow/Column` is returning the "min" point of the selection over the range that is selected. Based on "minimal" testing, there doesn't seem to be any immediate way to determine which cell the mouse was released from

Answer (score 2):

Based on my limited testing, the only "seemingly" reliable way to get the start point of the selection, is to use the row and column `ListSelectionModel` directly...

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(10, 10);
JTable table = new JTable(model);
ListSelectionListener listener = new ListSelectionListener() {
    @Override
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
        if (e.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
            return;
        }
        int row = table.getSelectionModel().getAnchorSelectionIndex();
        int col = table.getColumnModel().getSelectionModel().getAnchorSelectionIndex();

        System.out.println(row + "x" + col);
    }
};

table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(listener);
table.getColumnModel().getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(listener);
```

Now, this example is interacting with the `ListSelectionModel` via a `ListSelectionListener` to demonstrate the idea, but you could just as easily incorporate the idea into your `MouseListener` and extract the selection `anchor` indices there

Comment: It all seems a little complex for what I imagine is a common requirement - or am I missing something here. Maybe I could use the X,Y co-ords minus parent x,y then . . . . see what I mean? 

Is this the 'preferred' method for Table layout of rows/columns?

Could I do this by controlling the HIGHLIGHT and forcing it to stay on the table.getRow() and table.getColumn() results?

Comment: Alot comes down to what you might consider a "common requirement" - because of the way `MouseListener` works, you won't get a `mouseClicked` event, only a `mouseReleased` event.  The `JTable` API makes "best effort" guesses over what it should return when you call `getSelectedRow/Column` based on the designer's choices (just happens to return the minimum selected value). The `ListSelectionModel` does provide some functionality (`anchor` and `lead`). This is how it's worked for 20+ years, so I'm not sure I really see your point.

Comment: @JackDaw You could use the mouse x/y point to calculate the cell that the `MouseReleased` event occurred, but you'd then have to test to see if it is actually within the selected range of cells anyway. Could you control the highlights? So, you want to implement your own `ListSelectionModel` for both the rows and columns?

Comment: I was thinking if I can control the Selected Row I can force the selection to be the first cell clicked - that way there is no confusion over which one will be deleted

Comment: @JackDaw All this solution does is gets to the heart of the problem.  `getSelectedRow/Column` uses the same `ListSelectionModel`s to return their values, I've just directly to them to get the values I want instead